# Getting the max for the first element in an array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Say I have documents like the ones below:

```
{
   email: "test@test.com",
   values: [2,9]
},
{
   email: "test@test.com",
   values: [1,3]
},
{
   email: "another@email.com",
   values: [4,5]
},
```

And I would like to get the maximum value for the first element in the `values` array for each email (so `2` for `test@test.com`.  Is it possible to apply `$max` only to the first element of the array?  I tried the methods below:

```
db.test.aggregate({$group:{_id: '$email', max: {$max: "$values[0]"}}})
```

and

```
db.test.aggregate({$group:{_id: '$email', max: {$max: "$values.0"}}})
```

but neither seem to work (they return either `null` or an empty array for `max`).  Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close try, but unfortunately the standard form of projection available to methods like `.find()` are not available to the aggregation framework. You have to get a little more involved to get what you want.

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    // Unwind the arrays
    { "$unwind": "$values" },

    // Get the first value out of each document. Yes, order is respected.
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "email": { "$first": "$email" },
        "firstValue": { "$first": "$values" }
    }},

    // Then get "max" per grouping key
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$email",
        "value": { "$max": "$firstValue" }
    }}
])
```

This works because [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) pulls the "first" match on the "grouping boundary" and the order of the array is respected when unwinding the array content.

So the "first" [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage gets the "first" array element in the document. And the "second" [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage performs the [**`$max`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) over all of those values once they have been extracted.

P.S. Don't ask how to get the "nth" value as that is another question entirely, and much more involved. If you follow it through, there is a logical progression to do that though. It's not an optimal solution, but it can be done.

Believe me, in that we have been hanging out for "slice" projections and "limits" on [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) operations for some time now. It may happen some day.

Comment: just brilliant as always, please start your blog about mongo

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a shorter and more universal solution which works for any index of an array:

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {$project: {email: "$email", first_value:
      {$arrayElemAt: [ "$values", 0]}}},
  {$group: {_id: '$email', value: {$max: '$first_value'}}}
])
```